# Binary search, return value not modified

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Why is my `res` variable not modified during the recursion process? Thank you!

```
# Input [-1,0,3,5,9,12]
# output: -1
# expected: 4


class Solution:

    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        # boundary condition
        if not nums:
            return -1

        res = -1
        def binarySearch(nums, left, right):
            mid = (left + right) // 2
            # find the res, modify the `res` variable
            if target == nums[mid]:
                global res
                res = mid
                print(res) ##### print line, res: 4

            # base case
            if left >= right:
                return 
            if target < nums[mid]:
                binarySearch(nums, left, mid-1)
            if target > nums[mid]:
                binarySearch(nums, mid + 1, right)

        binarySearch(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `res` , declared as `res = -1` is local not global. The lines:

```
global res
res = mid
```

refer to a global variable `res`, i.e. if you call `res` outside of this class, it will have the desired value.

You can achieve the desired result as follows:

```
class Solution:

    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        # boundary condition
        if not nums:
            return -1

        self.res = -1
        def binarySearch(nums, left, right):
            mid = (left + right) // 2
            
            if target == nums[mid]:
                self.res = mid
                print(self.res) ##### print line, res: 4

            # base case
            if left >= right:
                return 
            if target < nums[mid]:
                binarySearch(nums, left, mid-1)
            if target > nums[mid]:
                binarySearch(nums, mid + 1, right)

        binarySearch(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
        return self.res
```

More on python `global` keyword [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword).